# Multiple URL Schemes in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, url

I'm trying to add URL schemes to my iOS app such that multiple URL schemes can target my app, but they will all be under the same identifier. To my understanding, I can only have one URL scheme for the identifier. [image: URL Scheme 1]. But I want the app to respond to multiple similar URL Schemes. So it would also respond to a scheme like this. [image]. The only way I know how is to manually add each URL scheme as follows: [image]. Does anyone know of a solution that allows all URLs of a certain pattern?

Answer (score 0):

There is no technical reason to have all your urls have the same Identifier. Apple recommends you use reversed DNS style names to ensure uniqueness. I usually use `<bundle ID here>.schema_name`

```
Identifier                     Scheme
----------                     ------
com.mycompany.myapp.schema1    schema1
com.mycompany.myapp.schema2    schema2
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit `Info.plist` to add `URL Types` -> `Item` -> `URL Schemes`'s String values.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate them by comma.

[image]